# MVC filter attribute creating session doesn't work, returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Moving an application to MVC and I thought an attribute [action] would be a good spot for dealing with session.

As I step through it the session gets set but in the controller it is null and on page refresh it doesn't hold.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Attribute

```
public class SetPageDefaultAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _sessionName = "PLANIT";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Page page;
        page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionName] as Page;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionName] != null)
        {
            page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionName] as Page;
        }
        else
        {
            //  set default page
            page = new Page();
        }
        page.Variables.CurrentController = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();
        page.Variables.CurrentAction = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower();

        //  return to session
        HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionName] = page;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
[SetPageDefault]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {

        var f = this.HttpContext.Session["PLANIT"];


        return View();
    }
}
```

So I changed the attribute to this...

```
public class SetPageDefaultAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _sessionName = "PLANIT";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Page page;
        page = (Page)filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_sessionName] as Page;

        if (page != null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //  set default page
            page = new Page();
        }
        page.Variables.CurrentController = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();
        page.Variables.CurrentAction = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower();

        //  return to session
        filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_sessionName] = page;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
```

Controller does this...

```
[SetPageDefault]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {

        var f = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["PLANIT"];


        return View();
    }
}
```

It is still null on a page refresh as it hits the attribute again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain that this will work, but it might be because you need to set the value within the `filterContext` that is available to you within `OnActionExecuting`:

```
public class SetPageDefaultAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _sessionName = "PLANIT";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Page page;
        page = (Page)filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_sessionName] as Page;

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_sessionName] != null)
        {
            page = (Page)filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_sessionName] as Page;
        }
        else
        {
            //  set default page
            page = new Page();
        }
        page.Variables.CurrentController = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();
        page.Variables.CurrentAction = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower();

        //  return to session
        filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_sessionName] = page;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
```